# What is, explicitly, a pullback in the category of $L_\infty$ algebras?

Tags: higher-category-theory, a-infinity-algebras, pullback

I was wondering if the category of $L_\infty$ algebras is complete and in particular I am looking for an explicit construction of the pullback for

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
 @. B\\
  \phantom V @VV b V\\
A @>>a> C
\end{CD}
in the case that $A, B, C$ are Lie-n-algebras, i.e. concentrated in only finitely many degrees.

I cannot find any reference suited to my basic knowledge of category theory.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It depends on the morphisms you take. With "strict" ones, yes, with $\infty$-morphisms I don't know for sure, but in those cases one is often more interested in the *homotopy* colimit, which does exist.

Comment: Hi @FernandoMuro and thanks! 
In my case, I'm not considering strict $L_\infty$-morphisms. 
By the way, how can I argue the existence of homotopy limits? Does it follow from the fact that the category of $ L_\infity$ algebras is an algebra over an operad?
(sorry for the naive questions, but I'm a beginner in these things)

Comment: you're right, your guess is correct.